# What exactly does the "--compress" in "gcloud compute scp --compress" do?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp#--compress), it simply says:

> `--compress`
>
> Enable compression.

At first I tried copying a folder from a remote VM onto my local machine with this flag expecting perhaps an auto compression into a `.zip` or `.gz` format, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Anyone have a better clue?

Comment: It does the same as `-C` option for  `scp` comand. Check man page.

Comment: You might need to add those flags for compression, just like in Linux, after the `compress` command, for example `--compress -fxzv`. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-compress-command